# How to solve "Access violation reading location" error in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am getting the following runtime error in using OpenCV for grabcut.

`"Access violation reading location"`

What I am trying to do is give seeds from a face detector and a backgroundsubtractor to grabcut. 
The seeds from my face detector are stored in `PrFg_seed_FaceExtended` (Face Dectection rectangle extended till the last row), `Fg_seed_inside_face` (A smaller rectangle inside the face detected)
All pixels in countoursFrame which are Red in colour are additional pixels that I want to add to the seed. Any ideas how I could do that?

The funny thing is that this runtime error comes in after three frames have been processed in the video.

The code seems to be working fine if I exclude the for loop where I am trying to mark red pixels from `contoursFrame` as GC_PR_FGD.

`contoursFrame` is just a clone of frame. I draw contours using the drawContours function on `contoursFrame`.

Code Snippet:

```
cv::Mat1b markers(frame.rows,frame.cols);
        cv::Mat1b fg_seed_inside_face = markers(rectangle_inner);
        cv::Mat1b Prfg_seed_FaceExtended = markers(rectangle_outer);

        markers.setTo(cv::GC_PR_BGD);
        Prfg_seed_FaceExtended.setTo(cv::GC_PR_FGD);
        fg_seed_inside_face.setTo(cv::GC_FGD);





        for(i=0;i<frame.rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<frame.cols;j++){
                if ((contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[0]==0) && (contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[1]==0) && (contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[2]==255)){
                    //cout << "\nFound a red pixel";
                    markers.at<uchar>(i,j) = cv::GC_PR_FGD;
                }
            }
        }

        waitKey(100);


        cv::Mat bgd, fgd;
        int iterations = 1;
        cv::grabCut(frame, markers, cv::Rect(), bgd, fgd, iterations, cv::GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);
        cout << "Grabcut Worked!";
        cv::Mat1b mask_fgpf = ( markers == cv::GC_FGD) | ( markers == cv::GC_PR_FGD);
```

Comment: You should provide more info: in which line does the error occur? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: I have been manually debugging the code. It gets stuck at the `if ((contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[0]==0) && (contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[1]==0) && (contoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[2]==255))`
Also, after running the program again, I realised that it gets stuck after different number of frames every time I run the program.
That is, the number of "GrabCut Worked" messages differ everytime I run the program.

Comment: Another pattern I noticed is that if I use a video with a higher resolution (1280X720), it can't process even a single frame. For videos with lower resolutions (320X340) it stops after a few frames. Could this be something to do with releasing variables? As of now I am not releasing any variable whatsoever. I am not sure what all needs to be released. new to opencv.

Comment: You're using [`Point(int _x, int _y);`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point) but supplying `(row,col)` locations.  It'll crash unless you have a square frame, but with more columns than rows, your going to read a lot further out of the frame's data buffer and probably crash sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`Point(int _x, int _y)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point) but supplying (row,col) according to your for loops. It'll crash unless you have a square frame, but with more columns than rows, your going to read a lot further out of the frame's data buffer and probably crash sooner.  This is because `cv::Mat` stores data in [row-major order](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (one row after another).

Notice that the [docs for `at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) declare the `at(int i, int j)` and `at(Point pt)` usages, and specify `pt` as:

```
pt – Element position specified as Point(j,i)
```

This means you need to swap `i` and `j` or just don't use `Point` when calling `at`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what @chappjc's comment means, but I think he did point out the root of the problem.

It was solved by making the following change:

```
if (
    (countoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(i,j).val[0]==0) && 
    (countoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(i,j).val[1]==0) && 
    (countoursFrame.at<Vec3b>(i,j).val[2]==255)
)
```

Basically, I thought Point(i,j) will be accessing the i,j pixel in the countoursFrame. By using val for accessing the pixel, my problem was solved.

Comment: `Point(i,j)` will be accessing the `i`th column and `j`th row, not the other way around.  OpenCV flips between x,y and row,col too much, IMO.

Comment: Oh! No wonder. Now it makes sense. I guess it is safer to use val, in that case.

Comment: `val` is actually not necessary here. You can use `[]` as the operator is defined for element access so you don't need to specify the member array `val`.